# Implementing edit action in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I  seen many examples of edit actions in asp.net mvc 3 and that's why I confused. For example, how does work UpdateModel and TryUpdateModel methods?  Or how to implement edit action if I want to update not all fields?

Could anyone give me a link about implementing edit action in asp.net 3?

Answer (score 1):

Best way to update only desired fields is create separate view model for it. For example, imagine you've got user class like this

```
public class User
{
     public int Id {get;set;}
     public string UserName {get;set}
     public bool IsAdmin {get;set;}
}
```

And suppose you do not wish to let user supply value for `IsAdmin` property. You create view model like this *(no IsAdmin field)*

```
public class EditUserViewModel
{
     public int Id {get;set;}
     public string UserName {get;set}
}
```

And the edit action pseudo something

```
public ActionResult Edit(EdituserViewModel model)
{
     If(ModelState.IsValid)
     {
        User user = _repository.GetUser(model.Id);
        user.UserName = model.UserName;
        _repository.Update(user);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }
     return View(model);
}
```

This way, there's no possiblity to supply IsAdmin from client side. You may also want to take a look at [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) and [Jimmy Bogard's blog](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/) for mapping view models to domain models. Jimmy's got the post about using ViewModels and AutoMapper in asp.net mvc too.

Comment: How do UpdateModel and TryUpdateModel  work? Which data provider they use? And how to bind EdituserViewModel with view?

Comment: @model of the view should be EditUserViewModel, and generate editors for it, normally. And I do not understand about data provider, do you mean value provider? UpdateModel and TryUpdate model take initial object on which they perform binding

Comment: Where to read about the UpdateModel and TryUpdate model binding? Could you give me any link? I've not found anything about it.

Comment: Why would you need them? MSDN has got small but enough documentation about it. They are used to manually invoke binding process, nothing more.